# Char movement, getting x/y speeds from 2 points

Tags: java, math

So i'm trying to make a program in java and i need to figure out how much I should add to x and y to make the player movement a constant speed at any angle. The information i have is 2 points, a starting point and an and and I need the char to move from a to b at a constant speed. I'm currently trying to figure out a bunch of different Math methods but I just cant get it right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain what you have tried and sample code as the readers of this site are generally not psychic.

Comment: I was just looking for help behind the math not the code specifically for which all the info to answer my question was provided but i will try to make my questions more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically (I won't provide code, sorry), assuming you can move in any direction on a two dimensional plane, from the top of my head it could be something like this (taken from old school geometry):

1. Having a speed, let's say 20 pixels per second (it could also be any other unit you chose, including in-game distance)
2. Having a polling system, where you have 2 main variables: the last known coords for the char (point A: Ax, Ay), the time of the last known update.
3. Having the time of the current update.
4. Having the coords for the destination (point B: Bx, By).
5. Figure out the current position of your character, which could be done like this (without converting from cartesian to polar coord system):
6. Figure out angle of movement: find the deltas for X and Y (`Dx=Bx-Ax` and `Dy=By-Ay` respectively), and use tangent to find the angle where `Angle = tan-1(Dy/Dx)`.
7. Figure out the travelled distance (TD) from last poll to current poll where `TD = speed * elapsed time`
8. Figure out the coords for the new position (Cx and Cy) using sine and cosine, where travelled X is `Tx=TD*sin(Angle)` and travelled Y is `Ty=TD*cos(Angle)`.
9. Now add the travelled distances to your original coords, and you get the current position. Where `Cx=Ax+Tx` and `Cy=Ay+Ty`.

How "smooth" movement is depends highly on the quality of your polling and somehow also on rounding for small distances.

Comment: Though I solved the problem without looking at this question again this was pretty much the answer i was looking for. I didn't want code just the math behind it and this is pretty much what I did so thanks anyways.

Comment: @LethalGames Even though this was my answer and I think it is "classically correct", I'd like to point out that Nicos answer leads to the same result in a more elegant way, without the use of trigonometry and likely less CPU costly. You might still want to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple. You have points `A (A.x, A.y)` and `B (B.x, B.y)` and need the update for your character position.

Start by calculating the direction vector `dir = B - A` (subtract component-wise, such that `dir.x = B.x - A.x; dir.y = B.y - A.y`).

If you add this entire vector to your character's position, you will move it by `sqrt(dir.x^2 + dir.y^2)` (Pythagorean theorem). Hence, the speed will be: `speed = sqrt(dir.x^2 + dir.y^2) / frameTime`.

So if you want a constant speed, you have to find a multiple of the direction vector. This will be:

```
update = dir * speed / sqrt(dir.x^2 + dir.y^2) * frameTime
characterPosition = characterPosition + update
```

Don't bother with angle calculations. Vector arithmetic is usually way more robust and expressive.

Comment: Mmm. Anything to avoid trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

Since u didn't provide us code I can just guess what exactly you are trying. 
So I'll start with some basics. 
I guess you are not just trying to make a program 
but the basic movement of an 2d based game engine.

However a constant moving is based of an update method 
that reads the player input about 30 times while rendering.
Example from my Projects:

```
public void run() {
    boolean isRunning = true;
    long lastNanoTime = System.nanoTime(),nowNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double secondAsNano = 1000000000.0;
    final double sixtiethOfSecondAsNano = secondAsNano / 30.0;
    int delta = 1;
    while(isRunning){
        nowNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
        if(delta * sixtiethOfSecondAsNano + lastNanoTime < nowNanoTime){
            update();
            delta++;
            if(delta == 30){
                delta = 1;
                lastNanoTime = nowNanoTime;
            }
        }
        render();
    }
}

public update(){
    if(Input.moveUP) setPlayerY(getPlayerY() - 0.2);
    if(Input.moveDOWN) setPlayerY(getPlayerY() + 0.2);
    if(Input.moveRIGHT) setPlayerX(getPlayerX() + 0.2);
    if(Input.moveLEFT) setPlayerX(getPlayerX() - 0.2);
}
```

I just cut it down to be easy readable so it might not work correct but it should explain you how its basically done.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out almost an hour after posting this. Sorry that my question was so vague, what I was looking for was the math behind what i was trying to do not the code itself but thanks to people who answered. Here is the solution I came up with in code :

```
            if (q.get(0)[0][0] > q.get(0)[1][0]) {
                if(q.get(0)[0][0] == q.get(0)[1][0]) {
                    currentLocation[0] -= 5 * Math.cos((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                    currentLocation[1] += 5 * Math.sin((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                }
                else{
                    currentLocation[0] -= 5 * Math.cos((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                    currentLocation[1] -= 5 * Math.sin((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                }
            } else {
                if(q.get(0)[0][0] == q.get(0)[1][0]) {
                    currentLocation[0] += 5 * Math.cos((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                    currentLocation[1] -= 5 * Math.sin((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                }
                else{
                    currentLocation[0] += 5 * Math.cos((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                    currentLocation[1] += 5 * Math.sin((Math.atan(((double) q.get(0)[0][1] - (double) q.get(0)[1][1]) / ((double) q.get(0)[0][0] - (double) q.get(0)[1][0]))));
                }
            }
```

I figured out a way to get the result I wanted though I probably over complicated it. q is an ArrayList that holds 2d arrays that are 2x2 [a/b][x/y]. and currentLocation a 2 index array that's just [x/y]. The result is the affect I wanted where it draws a line in (X units) a pass from point a to b in any direction at the same speed. This question was poorly worded and i'm sorry for wasting peoples time.